# dynamic size for microphone input

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am using unity3d to record some input from the microphone using:

```
getAudioSource.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true,20, 44100);
```

The problem is that this records for a standard time period of 20 secs, which i don't want. I would like to record untill a finish a recording by:

```
Microphone.End(deviceName);
```

and the resulting clip should have the exact size i recorded, not a standard 20 secs. Right now, if i end the recording after 3 secs, the resulting audio is 20 secs in length. I would like it to have 3 secs.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

the size isn't changeable, it's fixed size.. but i did manage to trim the audio to the actual size.

**UPDATE**

```
    AudioClip ac = getAudioSource.clip;
    float lengthL = ac.length;
    float samplesL = ac.samples;
    float samplesPerSec = (float)samplesL/lengthL;
    float[] samples = new float[(int)(samplesPerSec * timeSinceRecordStarted)];
    ac.GetData(samples,0);

    getAudioSource.clip = AudioClip.Create("RecordedSound",(int)(timeSinceRecordStarted*samplesPerSec),1,44100,false,false);

    getAudioSource.clip.SetData(samples,0);
```

where *timeSinceRecordStarted* is the length in secs of the recording and *getAudioSource* initially holds the microphone audio clip.